# Is it possible to use the libicu used by qt?

Tags: c++, qt5, icu

My Qt project use libicu for codec detection. But when building it using CMake & make, it show the following warning:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.56, needed by /opt/qt5/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.0, may conflict with libicui18n.so.60
```

The ICU used by my program is installed via apt on ubuntu 18, and the version is 60.2.
But the Qt used by my program is installed manually by the online installer, and the version of ICU is 58.x.

The reason why I don't installed qt via apt is that the project uses the features introduced in Qt5.15, and currently the highest version of Qt from apt is 5.12(on ubuntu 20.04).

When I scanning libraries, I find libicui18n in the qt root.
So I wonder if I can directly use it.
Or is there any way to solve this conflict?

Of course, rebuilding qt or building it on Arch Linux are possible solutions.
But this is quite complex, especially my program will be built on three platforms.

Comment: The project is on github: [cpeditor](https://github.com/cpeditor/cpeditor), [pr](https://github.com/cpeditor/cpeditor/pull/469)

Comment: You probably just need to find the headers of the icu library used by qt.

Comment: Yes, but qt don't installed them together. I don't think checking its version and downloading source manually is a good choice.

Comment: I would try to do the folowing: install libicu 56 from http://site.icu-project.org/download in opt, remove explicit dependency to libicu in cmake project files and just add a " /opt/<libicu-include-dir>" to the include directories of target depending on libicu, for example by using `include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM <dir>)` cmake command.